# PHP : sort variables values in the array and get the top 3 variable name

Tags: php

In this `$Bank[1],$CreditCard[1],$Transport[1],$Tax[1],$Insurance[1]` are part of another array.Here I am trying to get top 3 category list. I am using below code, but it will only give me value of each variables. Is there anyway I can get the variable name also, same `Bank,CreditCard etc`

```
$list = array($Bank[1],$CreditCard[1],$Transport[1],$Tax[1],$Insurance[1]);
rsort($list);
echo "Top 3 Categories : ";
echo implode(", ", array_slice($list, 0, 3));
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Then you will need to make an associative array and use [arsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

Comment: Hard to get variable names, better to add the keys yourself.